How to convert a datetime string to DateTime in C#
I have a string that is already in the required datetime format. Can I convert it directly into a DateTime in C#?
I tried the following:
string datetimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";      
DateTime.ParseExact("2024-09-10 12:13:08.712", datetimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime.ParseExact("2024-09-10 12:13:08.712", datetimeFormat, null);

The output I get for both of these is a different datetime format:

9/10/2024 12:13:08 PM

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CEOERT

For me it gives consistent results..

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")); A Datetime is just a point in time. How you display it is not stored in the DateTime but in the string representation. And i guess the question is a duplicate.

"The output I get for both of these is a different datetime format" - That's your error, there. DateTime has no format. You give it one -- explicitly or implicitly -- when you render it into a string representation. Explicitly if you do e.g. .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") and implicitly if you look at it in the debug variable values window, for example.

The reason you get a different output is that the DateTime.ToString() has a default format it will use to convert the DateTime to string.
You can change the output format by passing the format to the .ToString() like:
string datetimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
            
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2024-09-10 12:13:08.712", datetimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("2024-09-10 12:13:08.712", datetimeFormat, null);
            
Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString(datetimeFormat));        
Console.WriteLine(dt2.ToString(datetimeFormat));

This will print:
2024-09-10 12:13:08.712
2024-09-10 12:13:08.712


This made it all clear in my head, thank you! So the dt1 will actually get the format that I specified and the issue occurs when printing a DateTime variable..

@ginou 'So the dt1 will actually get the format that I specified'. A DateTime has no format. it's just a point in time, nothing else. ParseExact uses the format to parse the dateTime string, and convert to string to a DateTime. Only when you print the DateTime, it is converted back to a string, and a format is needed.

@Peter B thank you for the clarification!

using System;
using System.Globalization;

string datetimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2024-09-10 12:13:08.712", datetimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string formattedDateTime = parsedDateTime.ToString(datetimeFormat);

Console.WriteLine(formattedDateTime);  // Outputs: 2024-09-10 12:13:08.712

Try this

Please explain how this snippet solves the i ssue. Code-only answers are not good answers
